# Unable to generate TF Records

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tfrecord

> I am trying to generate TF Records using this command

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

> Can anybody please tell why I am facing this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 168, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 158, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 132, in create_tf_example
    classes.append(class_text_to_int(str(row['class'])))
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in class_text_to_int
    return label_map_dict[row_label]
KeyError: 'person'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 168, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 158, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 132, in create_tf_example
    classes.append(class_text_to_int(str(row['class'])))
  File "/Users/kesharwani.prashant/Files/Real-Time-Sign-Language-Detection/Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in class_text_to_int
    return label_map_dict[row_label]
KeyError: 'person'
```

Getting this error while generating a TF Record for training a Model.